# For...Next with expanding range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of formulae in cells D5:D103 of a report, which link to another sheet in the book. Columns A:C contain text results, Column D has $ amounts as the results. A4:D4 contains headings for the data, and A1:D3 is a general heading to describe the report. The location of the last row will change each month, could be >103, could be <103.

After every 16 rows of data I need to insert 3 rows by 4 columns pasted from a named range in the sheet, and insert a total of the 16 rows in column D of the 2nd of the 3 rows. I then add a page break below ( a crude pagination exercise dictated by other requirements).

The following code achieves most of this:-

```
Dim Formula1 As String

Formula1 = "=SUM(R[-17]C:R[-2]C)"

For i = 21 To (Range("a5", Range("d4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 4) Step 19

    Range("Total_credit").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("a" & i).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("a" & i).Offset(1, 3) = Formula1

    Selection.Offset(3).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

Next i
```

However, I am left with a block of 19 rows of data at the bottom, which should be 2 blocks of 16 with the pasted text and a total below each (ideally there would be no blank rows in the last sequence, but I can live with that if I can get the rest right).  The same issue seems to occur when I make the block of data a few rows bigger i.e. the last total will always be in the same place (D117).

It appears the value of i is incrementing each loop, but this doesn't seem to be reflected in the process. I've tried all sorts of things and searched thoroughly to no avail, and my head is just spinning now. I'm sure someone will see instantly where I've gone wrong, it seems like it should be a simple fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you find your last row using .End(xlDown), that's the initial end. Your table gets added in between every set of data, but your "last row" doesnt change, so your loop stops prematurely.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, that confirms what I thought is the issue. Is there a way to fix this still using this method, or do I need to try something else? I had tried re-calculating "i" before "Next i" to no effect. Another way might be to increment i by 3 each time the loop runs, or to calculate the number of times the loop needs to run (count of rows/16, rounded up). But I can't figure how to make either of those work with my available time. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this in your code to manage the 'for loop' limit

```
Dim row_count As Double

row_count = Range("a5", Range("d5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
row_count = row_count + Round(row_count / 16) * 3 + 4
For i = 21 to row_count step 19 'change limit to the variable "row_count"
```

This should take care the 'For loop' limit. Or you can change it to a `Do While` loop where your controlled variables can change. Like this:

```
Dim Formula1 As String
Dim row_count As Long

Formula1 = "=SUM(R[-17]C:R[-2]C)"
'initialize variable
row_count = Range("a5", Range("d5").End(xlDown).Address).Rows.Count + 4 
i = 21 'initialize variable
'I added this before the loop to make the appearance clean
Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone 
Do While i < row_count
    Range("Total_credit").Copy: Range("a" & i).Insert xlDown
    Range("a" & i).Offset(1, 3) = Formula1
    Range("a" & I).Offset(3, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    i = i + 19 'increment variable
    're-initialize variable
    row_count = Range("a5", Range("d5").End(xlDown).Address).Rows.Count + 4 
Loop
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Many thanks, L42. Both solutions provide the same result, closer to what I need but still with 3 orphaned rows at the bottom with no total. I have played around with your suggestions, using a small amount of logic and a lot of trial and error, and find the following seems to work irrespective of the number of rows:-

Comment: Dim Formula1 As String
Dim row_count As Double

Formula1 = "=SUM(R[-17]C:R[-2]C)"

row_count = Range("a5", Range("d5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
i = 21

Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone

Do While i < row_count + 21

    Range("Total_credit").Select

    Selection.Copy

    Range("a" & i).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Range("a" & i).Offset(1, 3) = Formula1

    Selection.Offset(3).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

    i = i + 19 'increment variable

    row_count = Range("a5", Range("d5").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Loop

Comment: Also, in your first suggestion, I think Application.RoundUp is needed instead of just Round. Anyway, thanks again for your input, it was a big help. Please feel free to let me now if what I've arrived at is an accident waiting to happen, however!

Comment: np. yep, you can use the application.roundup. btw, what you did was ok specially if you need to maintain pagebreak length and its not an accident. you test it and did several trials. that's what programmers do. :)